# Developing a simple memory game

Tags: android, logic

I'm kinda new to Android, now I'm developing a very simple game, the logic is described as following: The user sees a 10-digit value after pressing a "Ready" `Button`. After 5 seconds, the value changes to
`* * * * * * *` and the user has to enter it in a text field (type "number") below. Under that text field there are 2 `Button`s: "Check" and "Give a hint". The check `Button` compares the user value to original value and changes a `TextView` according to the result("Correct"/"Incorrect"). The hint `Button` should show 3 random digits in the original value.

I have some questions on that small application:

1. I'm not sure which type I have to use to show the original value to the user: a
   `TextView`, a text field or something else?
2. How do I force the app to show 3 random digits from the original value in the case 
   when user presses the hint `Button`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1). I'm not sure which type I have to use to show the original value to the user: a TextView, a text field or something else?

For this TextView will do.

> 2). How do I force the app to show 3 random digits from the original value in the case when user presses the hint button?

Hopefully you are using **int** for storing 10 digit value (original value)

Make an array of int having size 10

```
int[] digits = new int[10];
```

Use for loop to separate all 10 digits from the 10 digit number.

```
int number = 1234567891
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  digits[i] = number % 2;
  number = number / 10;
}
```

This will give you array of 10 int values

Make object of java.util.Random class and fetch random values from 0-9

```
Random r = new Random();
int pos1 = r.nextInt(9);
```

> **nextInt(int n)** returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed int in the half-open range [0, n).

These values are positions from which you are going to retrieve digit from array
So this will give you random position between 0 and 9

Just make sure that each time you generate random value from Random, it should not be equal to previously generated values e.g. if you are generating random position for second digit you should check that it should be equal to first

you can show all 3 digits(fetched from 3 randomly generated positions) in TextView as a **hint**
Hope this will solve your problem

**Edited Part**
Set visibility of Textview to View.GONE
something like this
     private TextView tv;

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView01);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view){
      tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
});
```